# React Material UI Autocmplete with React-window rerenders at top of list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-window

I have recently started learning React and could use any help.

I am having an issue with the Material-ui autocomplete component. Need some real React gurus to figure this one out. The problem I am having is that when I select an option from the autocomplete drop down it resets to the top of the list. I am using react-window because the list is over 300 elements. The ingredient filter is the one that I am trying to fix, the other filters work fine. I have created code sandboxes that demonstrate what should happen and what is currently happening. I have messed around with React.memo but that does not have any affect on it. Please let me know if you have any ideas. The correct sandbox is from the material-ui site: [autcomplete component](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)

Correct: [correct sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-brkwt?file=/demo.js)

[correct gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG6fg.gif)

Issue: [issue sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jp3iz?file=/demo.js)

[issue gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ioh3.gif)

Please let me know if you need any clarification

Answer (score 0):

I had to use useCallback on ListboxComponent, please try now.
Link to code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-33l5y?file=/demo.js:11315-11331

Old answer:

Seems like when we call setIngredients it is re-rendering the component and causes the list to jump to top, memoizing the handleIngredients function seems to fix it.

```
const handleIngredients = React.useMemo((event, value) => {
  setIngredients(value);
}, []);
```

Comment: That changes fixes but the problem with the list not scrolling to the top but now setIngredients is not called anymore: [Link with change](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-j2wzg?file=/demo.js:9068-9081)