# React MUI Virtualized Autocomplete scrolls back to top when selecting an option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using reactMUI autocomplete with virtualization as the listbox is expected to have thousands of items. Virtualization works but if i add an onchange function the listbox scrolls back to top when selecting an item (multiple selection is allowed)
i've tried following the advice from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166255/react-material-ui-autocmplete-with-react-window-rerenders-at-top-of-list) but wrapping the listboxcomponent in useCallback did not solve the problem for me.
this is my component's code:

```
import { Autocomplete, Chip, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { ProductGroup, Product, NewGruppo } from "../code/Types";
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2"; // Grid version 2
import { ListChildComponentProps, VariableSizeList } from "react-window";

interface Props {
  selectedGroup: ProductGroup | undefined;
  onSelectedProductsChanged?: (products: Product[]) => void;
  selectedProducts: Product[];
}

export const ProductSelector: React.FC<Props> = ({
  selectedGroup,
  onSelectedProductsChanged,
  selectedProducts,
}) => {
  const [isLoadingProdotti, setIsLoadingProdotti] = React.useState(false);
  const [prodotti, setProdotti] = React.useState<Product[]>([]);
  const [selectedProductsCount, setSelectedProductsCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveProducts = async () => {
      // retrieve all products for the selected group using xrm webapi
      const xrm = window.parent.Xrm;
      try {
        setSelectedProductsCount(0);
        setIsLoadingProdotti(true);

        const result: NewGruppo = await xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(
          "new_gruppo",
          selectedGroup?.id ?? "",
          "?$select=new_gruppoid&$expand=new_new_gruppo_new_prodotto($select=new_prodottoid,new_idprodotto,new_name,_nk_lineaprodotto_value;$filter=statecode eq 0;$orderby=new_name asc)"
        );

        setProdotti((result.new_new_gruppo_new_prodotto as Product[]) ?? []);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoadingProdotti(false);
      }
    };

    if (!selectedGroup) {
      setProdotti([]);
    } else {
      retrieveProducts();
    }
  }, [selectedGroup]);

  /**
   * Handles the click event for a product chip.
   * @param productId The ID of the product associated with the clicked chip.
   */
  const handleChipClick = (productId: string) => {
    //open product form
    const xrm = window.parent.Xrm;
    xrm.Navigation.openForm({
      entityName: "new_prodotto",
      entityId: productId,
      openInNewWindow: true,
    });
  };

  const renderRow = (props: ListChildComponentProps) => {
    const { data, index, style } = props;
    const dataSet = data[index];
    const inlineStyle = {
      ...style,
      top: (style.top as number) + LISTBOX_PADDING,
    };
    const option = dataSet[1] as Product;

    return (
      <li {...dataSet[0]} style={inlineStyle}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">{option.new_idprodotto}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="body2">
              {option.new_name} -{" "}
              {
                option[
                  "_nk_lineaprodotto_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"
                ]
              }
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </li>
    );
  };

  function useResetCache(data: number) {
    const ref = React.useRef<VariableSizeList>(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (ref.current != null) {
        ref.current.resetAfterIndex(0, true);
      }
    }, [data]);
    return ref;
  }

  const OuterElementContext = React.createContext({});

  const OuterElementType = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
    const outerProps = React.useContext(OuterElementContext);
    return <div ref={ref} {...props} {...outerProps} />;
  });

  // Adapter for react-window
  const ListboxComponent = React.useCallback<
    React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<
      HTMLDivElement,
      React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>
    >
  >(
    function ListboxComponent(props, ref) {
      const { children, ...other } = props;
      const itemData: React.ReactNode[] = [];
      (children as React.ReactElement[]).forEach(
        (item: React.ReactElement & { children?: React.ReactElement[] }) => {
          itemData.push(item);
          itemData.push(...(item.children || []));
        }
      );

      const itemCount = itemData.length;
      const itemSize = 55;

      const getChildSize = () => {
        return itemSize;
      };

      const getHeight = () => {
        if (itemCount > 8) {
          return 8 * itemSize;
        }
        return itemData.map(getChildSize).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      };

      const gridRef = useResetCache(itemCount);

      return (
        <div ref={ref}>
          <OuterElementContext.Provider value={other}>
            <VariableSizeList
              itemData={itemData}
              height={getHeight() + 2 * LISTBOX_PADDING}
              width="100%"
              ref={gridRef}
              outerElementType={OuterElementType}
              innerElementType="ul"
              itemSize={() => itemSize}
              overscanCount={5}
              itemCount={itemCount}
            >
              {renderRow}
            </VariableSizeList>
          </OuterElementContext.Provider>
        </div>
      );
    },
    []
  );

  const LISTBOX_PADDING = 8; // px

  const handleSelectedProductsChanged = (products: Product[]) => {
    if (onSelectedProductsChanged) {
      onSelectedProductsChanged(products);
    }
    setSelectedProductsCount(products?.length ?? 0);
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      fullWidth
      disableListWrap
      disableCloseOnSelect
      multiple
      disabled={isLoadingProdotti}
      id="products-standard-unique-id"
      options={prodotti}
      getOptionDisabled={() => (selectedProductsCount ?? 0) >= 25}
      onChange={(_, values) => handleSelectedProductsChanged(values)}
      filterOptions={(options, state) => {
        return options.filter((o) => {
          const lowerInputValue = state.inputValue.toLowerCase();
          return (
            o.new_idprodotto.toLowerCase().includes(lowerInputValue) ||
            o.new_name.toLowerCase().includes(lowerInputValue)
          );
        });
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="standard"
          label={`Prodotti (${prodotti?.length})`}
          placeholder="Ricerca"
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(props, option, state) =>
        [props, option, state.index] as React.ReactNode
      }
      renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
        value.map((option, index) => (
          <Chip
            label={option.new_idprodotto}
            color="info"
            {...getTagProps({ index })}
            onClick={() => handleChipClick(option.new_prodottoid)}
          />
        ))
      }
      ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
      value={selectedProducts}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Why do you create everything inside the component. Move them outside. You should not create component inside another component. This may fix it

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean? i'm fairly new to react, and this is already a nested component that only renders the autocomplete

Comment: Go and play with it, you will see what rerender means, it executes the body of the component and everything inside it again and again. And so, if you create component inside another component, that component gets recreated on each render. This breaks the diffing algorithm

Comment: i don't think that's the problem unfortunately, because if i remove the onchange function it works as expected. the problem seems to be the same as the question i linked, moreover i've already tried to move this logic in the parent and topmost component and the problem persists. i'm fairly new to react, not to web development, i know the concept of render and rerenders, but thanks anyway

Comment: onChange changes the state, so it causes a rerender, so it recreates the components inside the component. I think this is the problem here. Move ```renderRow``` outside of ```ProductSelector```

Comment: thank you, i've just tried to do that but unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the above comment is correct, if anyone ever stumbles upon this, thanks [Oktay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13311273/oktay-yuzcan)
Moving all the render related funcions just outside of the ProductSelector component, but in the same file, resolved the problem, without having to use a callback hook or anything like this.
this is the complete working component code, it could be more beautiful, but for now it works:

```
import {
  Autocomplete,
  Chip,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  autocompleteClasses,
  styled,
} from "@mui/material";
import { ProductGroup, Product, NewGruppo } from "../code/Types";
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2"; // Grid version 2
import { ListChildComponentProps, VariableSizeList } from "react-window";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";

interface Props {
  selectedGroup: ProductGroup | undefined;
  onSelectedProductsChanged?: (products: Product[]) => void;
  selectedProducts: Product[];
}

const renderRow = (props: ListChildComponentProps) => {
  const { data, index, style } = props;
  const dataSet = data[index];
  const inlineStyle = {
    ...style,
    top: (style.top as number) + LISTBOX_PADDING,
  };
  const option = dataSet[1] as Product;

  return (
    <li {...dataSet[0]} style={inlineStyle}>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2">{option.new_idprodotto}</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="body2">
            {option.new_name} -{" "}
            {
              option[
                "_nk_lineaprodotto_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"
              ]
            }
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </li>
  );
};

function useResetCache(data: number) {
  const ref = React.useRef<VariableSizeList>(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current != null) {
      ref.current.resetAfterIndex(0, true);
    }
  }, [data]);
  return ref;
}

const OuterElementContext = React.createContext({});

const OuterElementType = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
  const outerProps = React.useContext(OuterElementContext);
  return <div ref={ref} {...props} {...outerProps} />;
});

// Adapter for react-window
const ListboxComponent = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>
>(function ListboxComponent(props, ref) {
  const { children, ...other } = props;
  const itemData: React.ReactNode[] = [];
  (children as React.ReactElement[]).forEach(
    (item: React.ReactElement & { children?: React.ReactElement[] }) => {
      itemData.push(item);
      itemData.push(...(item.children || []));
    }
  );

  const itemCount = itemData.length;
  const itemSize = 55;

  const getChildSize = () => {
    return itemSize;
  };

  const getHeight = () => {
    if (itemCount > 8) {
      return 8 * itemSize;
    }
    return itemData.map(getChildSize).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  };

  const gridRef = useResetCache(itemCount);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <OuterElementContext.Provider value={other}>
        <VariableSizeList
          itemData={itemData}
          height={getHeight() + 2 * LISTBOX_PADDING}
          width="100%"
          ref={gridRef}
          outerElementType={OuterElementType}
          innerElementType="ul"
          itemSize={() => itemSize}
          overscanCount={5}
          itemCount={itemCount}
        >
          {renderRow}
        </VariableSizeList>
      </OuterElementContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
});

const LISTBOX_PADDING = 8; // px

const StyledPopper = styled(Popper)({
  [`& .${autocompleteClasses.listbox}`]: {
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    "& ul": {
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
    },
  },
});

export const ProductSelector: React.FC<Props> = ({
  selectedGroup,
  onSelectedProductsChanged,
  selectedProducts,
}) => {
  const [isLoadingProdotti, setIsLoadingProdotti] = React.useState(false);
  const [prodotti, setProdotti] = React.useState<Product[]>([]);
  const [selectedProductsCount, setSelectedProductsCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveProducts = async () => {
      // retrieve all products for the selected group using xrm webapi
      const xrm = window.parent.Xrm;
      try {
        setSelectedProductsCount(0);
        setIsLoadingProdotti(true);

        const result: NewGruppo = await xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(
          "new_gruppo",
          selectedGroup?.id ?? "",
          "?$select=new_gruppoid&$expand=new_new_gruppo_new_prodotto($select=new_prodottoid,new_idprodotto,new_name,_nk_lineaprodotto_value;$filter=statecode eq 0;$orderby=new_name asc)"
        );

        setProdotti((result.new_new_gruppo_new_prodotto as Product[]) ?? []);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoadingProdotti(false);
      }
    };

    if (!selectedGroup) {
      setProdotti([]);
    } else {
      retrieveProducts();
    }
  }, [selectedGroup]);

  /**
   * Handles the click event for a product chip.
   * @param productId The ID of the product associated with the clicked chip.
   */
  const handleChipClick = (productId: string) => {
    //open product form
    const xrm = window.parent.Xrm;
    xrm.Navigation.openForm({
      entityName: "new_prodotto",
      entityId: productId,
      openInNewWindow: true,
    });
  };

  const handleSelectedProductsChanged = (products: Product[]) => {
    if (onSelectedProductsChanged) {
      onSelectedProductsChanged(products);
    }
    setSelectedProductsCount(products?.length ?? 0);
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      fullWidth
      disableListWrap
      disableCloseOnSelect
      multiple
      disabled={isLoadingProdotti}
      id="products-standard-unique-id"
      options={prodotti}
      getOptionDisabled={() => (selectedProductsCount ?? 0) >= 25}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.new_idprodotto}
      onChange={(_, values) => handleSelectedProductsChanged(values)}
      filterOptions={(options, state) => {
        return options.filter((o) => {
          const lowerInputValue = state.inputValue.toLowerCase();
          return (
            o.new_idprodotto.toLowerCase().includes(lowerInputValue) ||
            o.new_name.toLowerCase().includes(lowerInputValue)
          );
        });
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="standard"
          label={`Prodotti (${prodotti?.length})`}
          placeholder="Ricerca"
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(props, option, state) =>
        [props, option, state.index] as React.ReactNode
      }
      renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
        value.map((option, index) => (
          <Chip
            label={option.new_idprodotto}
            color="info"
            {...getTagProps({ index })}
            onClick={() => handleChipClick(option.new_prodottoid)}
          />
        ))
      }
      ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
      PopperComponent={StyledPopper}
      value={selectedProducts}
    />
  );
};
```